# Android date conversion for translation

Tags: java, android, date

I didn't find how to convert this string to a correct date:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sat, 26 Mar 2016 09:46 PM CET" (at offset 0)
```

I've tried a lot of things like:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm a z", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

With or without simple quote.

May somebody help me please?

The goal is to have it translate with user locale settings when displayed on is device.

This is the code use in apps:

```
try {
                                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm a z", Locale.ENGLISH);
                                    Date testDate = null;
                                    testDate = sdf.parse(loc_Value);
                                    Tracer.e(mytag + "Date conversion", "Works");
                                    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
                                    String newFormat = formatter.format(testDate);
                                    value.setText(newFormat);
                                } catch (Exception ex) {
                                    ex.printStackTrace();
                                    Tracer.e(mytag + "Date conversion", "Error: " + ex.toString());
                                    value.setText(loc_Value);
                                }
```

Comment: Parsing strings into date-time objects, and adjusting time zones, has been covered many many times on Stack Overflow already. Please search thoroughly before posting.

Comment: I search a lot i can confrim, but none as the correct Dateformat. I didn't find out the correct one. It is not a Timezone problem, but a convertion one. The string comes from a domogik plugin, and i want it to be translate in user language. The only way is to convert it to real date, and the redisplay it in a view.